# Automating refactoring for redundant Delphi code?

Tags: delphi, refactoring, automated-refactoring, delphi-11-alexandria

I wrote this redundant code consisting of **30** lines:

```
if Button = TMouseButton.mbLeft then
begin
  if pnlEndColor.ShowCaption then
  begin
    pnlStartColor.ShowCaption := False;
    pnlEndColor.ShowCaption := False;
    pnlStartColor.Color := ThisColor;
    pnlEndColor.Color := ThisColor;
  end
  else
  begin
    pnlStartColor.ShowCaption := False;
    pnlStartColor.Color := ThisColor;
  end;
end
else if Button = TMouseButton.mbRight then
begin
  if pnlStartColor.ShowCaption then
  begin
    pnlStartColor.ShowCaption := False;
    pnlEndColor.ShowCaption := False;
    pnlStartColor.Color := ThisColor;
    pnlEndColor.Color := ThisColor;
  end
  else
  begin
    pnlEndColor.ShowCaption := False;
    pnlEndColor.Color := ThisColor;
  end;
end;
```

I manually refactored the code by extracting it to a small method by applying just logic:

```
procedure TForm1.SetPanelColors(Panel1, Panel2: TPanel; const aColor: TColor);
begin
  if Panel2.ShowCaption then
  begin
    Panel1.ShowCaption := False;
    Panel2.ShowCaption := False;
    Panel1.Color := aColor;
    Panel2.Color := aColor;
  end
  else
  begin
    Panel1.ShowCaption := False;
    Panel1.Color := aColor;
  end;
end;
```

Then I used the method by these **4** lines of code (Savings of 26 lines compared to the previous redundant code):

```
if Button = TMouseButton.mbLeft then
  SetPanelColors(pnlStartColor, pnlEndColor, ThisColor)
else
  SetPanelColors(pnlEndColor, pnlStartColor, ThisColor);
```

How could such a refactoring of redundant code be automated? Are there any libraries or general resources for such a purpose?

Comment: Sometimes the "Extract method" option works, but typically you do this manually using the clipboard and class completion.

Comment: By chance, I came across the website of Refactor! Pro 3.0:
https://www.devexpress.com/aboutus/newsreviews/refactor30.xml
It would be fantastic having such a tool for Delphi!

Comment: Have a look at [MMX Code Explorer](https://www.mmx-delphi.de/) plugin

Comment: Regarding the refactoring ...
1)  There is still a good deal of redundancy in the procedure code. It can be reduced to :

```delphi
procedure TForm1.SetPanelColors(Panel1, Panel2: TPanel; const aColor: TColor);
begin
  if Panel2.ShowCaption then Panel2.Color := aColor;
  Panel2.ShowCaption := False;
  Panel1.ShowCaption := False;
  Panel1.Color := aColor;
end; 
```

2)  I think the blind 'if else' in the last section should probably be replaced with a case statement on mbLeft and mbRight.